# call a view from controller in secha touch MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to render a `view` which I create when the button on another `view` is clicked.

Here is my controller code, and I am following the `MVC architecture`

```
Ext.define('demo.controller.LoginController' , {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: { 

        refs:{

                loginAction: 'button[action=login]'

        },
        control:{

                loginAction: {

                    tap:'loginProcess'
                }
        }


    },
    loginProcess:function(button,e,opts){


         // Render View here


    }


});
```

I have searched and I came across `getMainView().push()` and `Ext.ViewPoart.add()` but it's not working. According to the MVC pattern how should call this view from a controller?

**EDIT**

code of `profilecontainer`

```
Ext.define('demo.view.ProfileContainer',{


            extend:'Ext.Panel',
            xtype:'profilecontainer',

             requires: [
        'Ext.Label'
    ],

             config: {

                items:[{
                            xtype:'label',
                            html:'hi'
                }]

            }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the ways you have tried should work, if you set them up correctly.

First, `getMainView().push(newView)` will work if `mainView` is an `Ext.navigation.View`.  See the docs for this method here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-push

You can also use `Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(newView)`, assuming you have no typos (your post says `ViewPoart`).  (`Ext.Viewport.add` will add the panel to the Viewport, but not set it as the active Card in the layout)

If neither of these are working, then you probably are not configuring your controller correctly.  If that is the case, ensure that your `loginProcess` method is being called.  If it is not, then your selector, `button[action=login]`, is not correct.

Comment: i have tried `Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype:'profilecontainer'});` where `profilecontainer`is my `View` and it is register in `app.js` and its `xtype` is define as `profilecontainer` but still not able to call that existing view , by the way login button event is being fired i have checked it

Comment: If that is the case, you'll need to post your code for the `profilecontainer`.  Are any errors showing up on the console?

Comment: no no errors , what i want to is to load completely a new view which has a list , see my edit for `profilecontainer`

Comment: Ok, try using `Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype:'profilecontainer'})` instead.

Comment: yeah Tht worked but how come other options isnt working ? can you please explain ?

Comment: Viewport uses `Card` layout, so just adding to it will not set it as the active item.  I will update my answer to reflect this info.